# log4j2-Cofiguration : Replace system variable value in log4j2 configuration file

Tags: java, regex, log4j2, talend

I am using external log4j configuration file and using file appender with system variable to get the log file name.
Below is my configuration of file appender

```
<File name="File" fileName="${sys:LOG_BASE_DIR}/${sys:TalendJob.log}-${date:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.log">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c -$${ctx:InterfaceName:-}- %replace{%msg}{&quot;Password&quot; :\s+(\S+)}{Password : *****}%n" />
    </File>
```

the ${sys:TalendJob.log} gives my value with suffix '.log'(eg. job1.log) and want to replace .log but not sure how I can achive it.
So currently my log files  is getting generated like job1.log-20220315030201.log and I want job1-20220315030201.log

${sys:TalendJob.log} value of this is not in under my control .I mean it is setted by some other process which I can not change.

So how I can replace .log to '' i.e empty

Comment: Does any one have any suggestion

Comment: If you can't edit this config file to just delete ".log", I don't know what you could do. You'll have to check the process creating this config file.

Comment: TalendJob.log is a varables which get replaced with Test.log and i wanted to replace the value of it .eg Test

Answer (score 2):

By changing Talend studio settings I managed to have some control over the file name.
From project settings, go to Build > Shell setting > Bat (assuming you are using windows), and add this right after the java command:

```
-DjobName=${talend.job.name}
```

This will create add a system property in the generated bat file, with a name of jobName and give it the job name as a value.
[image]

Now you can change your log4j2 config to use jobName instead of TalendJob.log:

```
<File name="File" fileName="${sys:LOG_BASE_DIR}/${sys:jobName}-${date:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c -$${ctx:InterfaceName:-}- %replace{%msg}{&quot;Password&quot; :\s+(\S+)}{Password : *****}%n" />
</File>
```

This only works if you run the job as a standalone (by running the .bat)

Comment: Oh Thanks alot Ibrahim.This is what I was loking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of placeholders in a Log4j 2.x configuration file:

- `${...}` lookups, which are accepted everywhere (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html)),
- `%{...}` patterns, which are only resolved by the `PatternLayout` and a few of other components (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns)).

The component properties that support patterns usually also support lookups at runtime, but the inverse is not true. Unfortunately the `fileName` property of the `FileAppender` does not accept patterns, while the `filePattern` property of the `RollingFileAppender` only accepts `%d` and `%i`.

To remove `.log` from the Java property value, you need to write your own [`StrLookup`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrLookup.html).